# Best way to get 5.5KVrms/7777VAC?

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage

What's the best way to get a 5.5KVrms (7,777V peak) full-wave AC signal at 60Hz strong enough to drive two 8-stage CW multipliers at 150pF per capacitor?

Image for reference:
[image]

Not a duplicate of "how to make a 120VAC power supply."

Comment: It is so obviously a different question it is absurd you would flag this a duplicate.

Comment: define "best": That term is not clear. Without that definition, your question remains unclear and inanswerable.

Comment: @CoryG It's so obviously asking for the same circuit to be powered, it is absurd that you'd complain unqualifiedly instead of highlighting the difference between your two questions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller There is an absurd amount of context in the question.  Output voltage, frequency and approximate load are all specified.  And yeah, it's the same project - two ENTIRELY different components.  You looked at images, saw they were the same and drew conclusions without regard to content.

Comment: @CoryG That "absurd" amount of information which makes it vastly different from your previous question is what makes the upvotes and suggestions pour in.

Comment: @winny I said "absurd" amount of "context", not "information."  Read both questions and if you don't see the difference you clearly lack any knowledge of electrical engineering and should forgo speaking on the subject.

Comment: Ah yes, that's exactly why everyone upvoted it and didn't mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @CoryG I think it's worth pointing out, having seen both questions, that you're not going about this the best way. For instance, a stabilised mains supply is unnecessary and insufficient (look up 'necessity and sufficiency' on wikipedia to appreciate the full meaning of that assertion) to get a stabilised HT supply. A Cockcroft Walton stack has a very high output impedance, so more control will almost certainly be needed. I would use a PC power supply to get a thruppy 12v supply, rip the primary off a MOT, and drive a few turn primary off 12v at 100Hz to a get the HT AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neon sign transformer driven from a lower than rated voltage.

Unfortunately, two microwave oven transformers (MOTs) back to back in anti-series driven at the rated voltage won't quite give you the voltage you need. MOTs are so agressively designed that there is no scope for increasing the input voltage a little. However, if you increase the input frequency, then the input voltage can be increased pro-rata, a 50% uplift in both could get you where you want to be.

Comment: @CoryG, I really think you underestimate the work people on here put into commenting on your question, reading the other question, explaining what you need to do to improve the quality, and you outright insult them. I'd kind of recommend not doing something like that if you want to appear to be a decent person.

Comment: "Everyone's telling me to improve my question. Everyone must be a bad-tempered, mean-spirited person" certainly sounds a bit narcissistic, especially coming from someone without a single positive-score post.